# DOMAttrModified doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, events, dom-events

I'm trying to trigger an event handler when a script modifies an `input` element (text field.)  On Internet Explorer, I can use the `onpropertychange` event, but on Firefox and other browsers there is no such event.  So, according to the [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html), it seems the `DOMAttrModified` event does exactly what I want.  But it doesn't fire in `Firefox 11`.

Here's a simple code snippet which reproduces the problem.  I have an input text field, and a button which adds a character to the `value` attribute of the input text field.  Clicking on the `add char` button should cause the `DOMAttrModified` event to fire:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addChar() {
                var q = document.getElementById("query");
                q.value += "X";
            }

            function loadevents() {
                var q = document.getElementById("query");
                q.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function() {alert("DOMAttrModified event!");
                }, false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="loadevents()">
        <input type="text" id="query">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="add char" onclick="addChar()">
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  (I know that DOM Level 3 **deprecates** this event, but there doesn't seem to be a viable alternative right now.  As far as I know, Firefox 11 still supports it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the value in an input doesn't fire the `DOMAttrModified` event, that's all..

You need to change the **attribute** of the input node, not the **property** of the variable.
 It's like the [difference between the two jQuery functions: `.prop` and `.attr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Read:

- [Which HTMLElement property change generates DOMAttrModified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9919594/601179)
- [this forum discussion](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1983083)

Comment: The discussion you linked to is talking about modifying the `value` attribute through *user input* (i.e. physical typing on the keyboard), not through a script.  Unless I'm totally misunderstanding the W3C docs, the `DOMAttrModified` event is supposed to be fire if an attribute is modified through a script.

Comment: @Channel72. You need to change the **attribute** of the input node, not the **property** of the element var. It's like the difference between the jQuery functions: `.prop` and .`attr`

Comment: Is there any event I can use that will be triggered if a script modifies the `value` property?

Comment: @Channel72. No there is no such event. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

(repeating my answer from [Which HTMLElement property change generates DOMAttrModified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919594/which-htmlelement-property-change-generates-domattrmodified) here, because it's relevant to this question):

Please also note that NO DOMAttrModified events will be fired when the 'disabled' attribute is set. So if your event is not firing, that could be the reason. This also goes for the IE-only 'onPropertyChange' event.